# Average Number on entries where ID is the same as another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, relational-database, average

I have a database I am making with Microsoft Access 2013, where there is 2 tables. First table has `productID` as the primary key, second table has a unique `reviewID` as well as the `productID` of the product that the review is referring to. In first table where the products information is kept, I want to have a field that averages the ratings that it was given in it's reviews (kept in second table).

How do I average it's rating without averaging the rating for all reviews, and only for reviews about that specific product?

Comment: Please, show table structure, some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Definitely post your structure and what you have tried but also look into the `Group By` SQL clause. This is what it is for.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your descriptions I've created a table called **tblProducts** with the following data:

[image]

I've then created a table called **tblReview** with the following data (here I've assumed you have a field to store a value for each review's rating that I've called *ReviewRating*.. and I've assumed that reviews are rated from 0-10):

[image]

I then created this query:

```sql
SELECT tblProducts.ProductName, Avg(tblReview.ReviewRating) AS AvgOfReviewRating
FROM tblReview INNER JOIN tblProducts ON tblReview.productID = tblProducts.productID
GROUP BY tblProducts.ProductName;
```

...which results in:

[image]

Note that this is a `SELECT` query, so it won't put the average review rating in to the original **tblProducts** table, for that you would need an `UPDATE` query. I wouldn't recommend that though as you'll have to remember to run the update before using **tblProducts** for anything that needs up-to-date averages.